# xjc: XML Validation issue

Tags: java, xml, xsd, xjc

I am trying to generate java code using *xjc*.

My *xsd* is having following element

```
    <xs:element name="DataRate">                                        
        <xs:attribute name="Limit" type="xs:decimal" use="optional" />                                            
    </xs:element>
```

and *xjc* is complaining with

```
[ERROR] s4s-elt-must-match.1: The content of 'DataRate' must match (annotation?, (simpleType | complexType)?, (unique | key | keyref)*)). A problem was found starting at: attribute.
```

After little investigation, i got to know that the *attribute* element is not wrapped with *complexType* and hence *xjc* is complaining. If I modify the xsd as

```
      <xs:element name="DataRate">
         <xs:complexType>
             <xs:attribute name="Limit" type="xs:decimal" use="optional" />
         </xs:complexType>    
      </xs:element>
```

it is working fine. But, as the xsd I am getting from 3rd party, I want to avoid the modification.

Is there any other way to do that?

Comment: Ask your third party to make the change.

Comment: It's a rule that elements with attributes are of a _complex type_. The XSD therefore must follow that rule. If it does not, it is invalid.

Comment: thx nikhil, but I am looking for that solution. I am looking for any other tool provided by jdk ( not http://xmlbeans.apache.org/ or http://www.castor.org/) or any way to tune xjc